# object top in VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Me and my teammate is getting hammered by this mystery.

While we are tracing some codes, we encounter something like this

```
 top.VARIABLE_NAME
 top.FunctionName(param)
```

We tried to trace the code for the object top, but it was not declared anywhere in the project, so we thought that it was a VBScript built-in object for global variables but there is not documentation for it.

so far we notice this line of code

```
ExecuteGlobal(strCode)
```

can this be the cause of that top object? please help us to understand this.

**Update**

It is weird but the HTML of our current project contains a lot of frames. but I don't know if that's the reason of using "top".

Here is the complete code/implementation for ExecuteGlobal(strCode)

```
       Sub Import(ByVal strFile)
                Dim objFs
                Dim WshShell
                Dim objFile
                Dim strCode

                Set objFs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
                Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                WshShell.CurrentDirectory = "E:\MyFiles\Documents\Dev\Tester\VBS\haha"
                Set objFile = objFs.OpenTextFile(strFile)
                strCode = objFile.ReadAll
                objFile.Close
                ExecuteGlobal(strCode)
       End Sub
```

if I print strCode, it contains this value.

```
sub HtmlCreator(arrObj)     
    for i = LBound(arrObj) to UBound(arrObj)
        if not isEmpty(arrObj(i)) then
            arrObj(i).innerHtml = "me"      
        end if
    next
end sub
```

sorry I can't post the exact code because of confidentiality but I hope you get the idea.
THANKS..

Comment: The object could be created dinamically. Replace the code you found `ExecuteGlobal(strCode)` with `MsgBox strCode: ExecuteGlobal(strCode)` for debug purposes, or use any debugger, like MS Script Editor (launch you script via eg `WScript.exe` with `//D` directive), VbsEdit or PrimalScript to inspect `strCode` value.

Comment: I thinks this is what I'm looking for, but I cant try it now. I'll comment my findings base on your comment tomorrow, thanks :)

Comment: hi @omegastripes, strCode contains the subs/functions of a specific file. I'll update my question for the complete code/implementation for ExecuteGlobal(strCode).

Comment: Yes, you've found it. And I see usual implementation of "include" sub. What is the _`strCode` value_?

Comment: @omegastripes - strCode contains the codes of the strFile. I'll update the entire value of strCode in my question. thanks

Comment: Well, if you can't debug this code, at least add `MsgBox TypeName(top)` to find out object type.

Comment: @omegastripes - what do you mean? I used `MsgBox TypeName(top)` and a message box pop-up with a text HTMLWindows2. I also tried  `MsgBox TypeName(strCode)` and it printed a text String.

Comment: Are you running VBScript within HTA?

Comment: @omegastripes - It is weird but the HTML of our current project contains a lot of frames. but I don't know if that's the reason of using "top". can you please give me an example. thanks a lot

Comment: @omegastripes - Sorry but I don't even know whats an HTA. I'd been with php, html, ruby and javascript, but I'm totaly new to VBScript. Hope you understand.

Comment: You have already answered your question.  Nested frames are referencing to the global scope variables and functions of main window via `top` object, that's the reason of using it. IMO you should accept @Ekkehard.Horner answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[top](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/top) is the top level window in the DOM hierarchy.

Demo:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script type="text/vbscript">
   MsgBox TypeName(window.top) & " " & CStr(window.top Is top) & " " & CStr(window Is top)
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi I think this is not what I'm looking for. Maybe something like top.window is close enough because I'm looking for top as the object not as a member of an object.

Comment: @Thorax - why do you think I included `CStr(window Is top)` in the demo?

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any idea what this mean `CStr(window Is top)`. In our current project all of the global functions and variables needs to have a prefix top(ex: top.myVar). If I'm not mistaken, I did not see anything related in windows positions in the project.